# How to make USB 3.0 devices enumerate as USB 3.0 version instead of USB 2.0 within Samsung S8+?

Tags: android, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver, samsung-mobile

Samsung Galaxy S8+ has a USB-C port supporting USB 3.0. But S8+ doesn’t always use USB 3.0 while being as a USB host, even if the USB device supports USB 3.0. After a few tests, I am pretty sure this should be a software issue rather than a hardware issue.

The OS in S8+ is Android 9.0, One UI 1.0.

[Connecting S8+ to a Windows computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlU5O.png), it proves S8+ does support USB 3.0.

[Connecting a USB 2.0 storage to S8+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiWps.jpg), naturally S8+ is using USB 2.0.

Running `lsusb` in terminal and getting information below

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0951:1624
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003
```

Running `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` saying

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 1
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0    
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev= 4.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=xhci-hcd.0.auto
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms
```

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 1
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 4.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=xhci-hcd.0.auto
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms
```

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0951 ProdID=1624 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=Kingston
S:  Product=DataTraveler G3
S:  SerialNumber=90B30300658D34AF
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=200mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
```

Using `dmesg` I get the following logs

```
[   45.024217] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[   45.024271] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   45.024324] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   45.024367] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
[   45.024415] usb usb1: SerialNumber: xhci-hcd.0.auto
[   45.029434] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[   45.029618] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[   45.029682] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[   45.029748] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[   45.029798] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
[   45.029856] usb usb2: SerialNumber: xhci-hcd.0.auto
[   45.220222] usb usb1-port1: port 1, status 0101, change 0000, 12 Mb/s
[   45.340092] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[   45.487933] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1624
[   45.488012] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   45.488084] usb 1-1: Product: DataTraveler G3
[   45.488136] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Kingston
[   45.488187] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 90B30300658D34AF
[   45.502519] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   45.508315] scsi host1: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[   45.509271] msm-dwc3 a800000.ssusb: 1-1 configured bMaxPower:200 (mA)
[  509.959021] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  510.180224] usb usb2: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  510.180971] usb usb1: USB disconnect, device number 1
```

which means the USB 2.0 storage is connected with USB 2.0. Nothing special.

[Connecting a USB 3.0 gigabit ethernet adapter (RTL8153) to S8+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqQiq.jpg), it shows S8+ is only using USB 2.0.

Running `lsusb` in terminal and getting information below

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8153
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003
```

Running `cat /sys/kernel/debug/usb/devices` saying

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 1
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0    
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev= 4.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=xhci-hcd.0.auto
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms
```

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480  MxCh= 1
B:  Alloc=  0/800 us ( 0%), #Int=  0, #Iso=  0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev= 4.04
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=xhci-hcd.0.auto
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=  0mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms
```

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  2
P:  Vendor=0bda ProdID=8153 Rev=30.00
S:  Manufacturer=Yixin
S:  Product=USB 10/100/1000LAN
S:  SerialNumber=000000001
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=350mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=00 Driver=r8152
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   2 Ivl=16ms
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 2 Atr=a0 MxPwr=350mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(comm.) Sub=06 Prot=00 Driver=
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=16ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 1 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS= 512 Ivl=0ms
```

Using `dmesg` I get different logs

```
[  597.485656] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[  597.485792] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[  597.485911] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[  597.486021] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
[  597.486157] usb usb1: SerialNumber: xhci-hcd.0.auto
[  597.488623] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[  597.488841] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[  597.488913] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[  597.488986] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[  597.489044] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
[  597.489110] usb usb2: SerialNumber: xhci-hcd.0.auto
[  597.690316] usb usb2-port1: port 1, status 0203, change 0000, 5.0 Gb/s
[  597.810618] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[  597.832835] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153
[  597.832910] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[  597.832981] usb 2-1: Product: USB 10/100 /1000LAN
[  597.833036] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Yixin
[  597.833085] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 000000001
[  597.842522] msm-dwc3 a800000.ssusb: 2-1 configured bMaxPower:288 (mA)
[  597.872971] usb usb2: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  597.873022] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  597.911621] usb usb1: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  599.051199] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[  599.051260] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[  599.051331] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[  599.051388] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
[  599.051455] usb usb1: SerialNumber: xhci-hcd.0.auto
[  599.054324] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[  599.054535] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[  599.054605] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[  599.054663] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[  599.054710] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.4.153-afaneh92 xhci-hcd
[  599.054762] usb usb2: SerialNumber: xhci-hcd.0.auto
[  599.250544] usb usb1-port1: port 1, status 0101, change 0000, 12 Mb/s
[  599.370730] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[  599.513064] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8153
[  599.513184] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[  599.513296] usb 1-1: Product: USB 10/100 /1000LAN
[  599.513385] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Yixin
[  599.513466] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 000000001
[  599.524718] msm-dwc3 a800000.ssusb: 1-1 configured bMaxPower:350 (mA)
[  599.693616] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
```

**which means the adapter is firstly connected to S8+ with USB 3.0, but immediately disconnected, then reconnected with USB 2.0!**

This phenomenon can be also seen here https://gtrusted.com/samsung-galaxy-s8-seems-to-downgrade-usb-3-1-hubs-speeds. In this review, apparently not all USB 3.0 devices can enumerate as USB 3.0 version within S8, and only Samsung Portable SSD T3 can when it is directly connected to S8. For me it seems like S8+ will determine whether to use USB 3.0 or not according to the brand of USB device.

Here are several ideas I considered in order to solve the problem:

1. Find out what android API actually do after physically plugging in a USB device, and try to modify or stop this behavior.
2. Disable USB 2.0.
3. After this behavior, set the USB device on `Bus 02`, or register the USB version as 3.0 manually.
4. After this behavior, disconnect and reconnect logically again, then see what happens.

I have tried logically disconnecting USB device by doing

```
echo '1-1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
```

and reconnecting it by doing

```
echo '1-1' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind
```

It won’t work because the USB device is still on `Bus 01` using USB 2.0.

I have also tried

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/remove
```

but I don’t know how to reconnect the USB device unless to physically replug it.

I appreciate any kinds of methods, tips or suggestions, no matter what, as long as it helps me to solve my problem. All I want is to make my S8+ USB 3.0 work with USB 3.0 devices.

Comment: 1) You didn't identify which version of Android OS you are using. 2) Be aware that the speed negotiation may be at the [USB HAL layer](https://source.android.com/docs/core/permissions/usb-hal) so you would need changing the code in the driver (hard/really hard).

Comment: I am not sure if USB 3.0 is available in OTG mode at all. When connected to an USB master (such as a Windows PC) it ca act as USB 3 device, but in OTG mode I am not sure if USB 3 is supported at all. Most likely it can not work as an XHCI USB master.